# Largest Possible Number after positing digit

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find largest possible Value after adding 5 at any place in given Number.

> Like:
>   I have 268 then there are possibilities.
>   5268. 2568. 2658. 2685.
>   So, max value is 5268 is the output.

I tried following but, didn't work as expected and seems not valid solution.

```js
function solution(N) {
    let largeVal = 0;
    
    let arr = String(N).split("");
    
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        
        var newFirstArr = [...arr]
        var newSecondArr = [...arr]
        
        newFirstArr.splice(i, 0, 5);
        newSecondArr.splice(i+1, 0, 5).join('');
        
        
        newFirstArr.join('') > newSecondArr.join('') ? largeVal = Number(newFirstArr.join('')) : largeVal = Number(newSecondArr.join(''));
        
    }
    
    return Number(largeVal);
}

console.log(solution(268));
```

Comment: Looks like 5 needs to be inserted before the first digit (from the left) that is smaller than (or equal to) 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only ever need to put a 5 to the right if it's lower than the 'current' on you're checking. Like so:

```js
function getNum(input_num, moving_num){
    var numbers = String(input_num).split("");
    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        var number = parseInt(numbers[i]);
        if(parseInt(moving_num) > number){
            numbers.splice(i, 0, moving_num);
            return numbers.join("");
        }
    }
    numbers.push(moving_num)
    return numbers.join("");
}

console.log( getNum(268, 5) ); //5268
console.log( getNum(123, 5) ); //5123
console.log( getNum(456, 5) ); //5456
console.log( getNum(654, 5) ); //6554
console.log( getNum(999, 5) ); //9995
```

Answer (score 3):

This is assuming you not change the order of the digits.

```js
function large5(n){
  return + String(n).replace(/^([5-9]*)(\d*)$/, "$15$2");
}
// tests
const tests = [236, 673, 882, 244, 5238];
tests.forEach(num => console.log(large5(num)));
```

Comment: That's clever :)

Comment: Advanced dark magiks. What's going on in the regex here?

Comment: the regex divide the number to "the numbers greater om equal to 5, from the left" , and "all the rest". then insert the 5 between this two groups

Comment: `$1` = group 1, then `5`, then `$2` = group 2. the groups identified by the `()`

Answer (score 0):

This will return the highest value from array. If you want to return smallest, replace `.pop()` with `.shift()`.

```js
const arr = [5268, 2568, 2658, 2685];

function test(n, arr) {
  const formattedArr = arr.filter(num => (num + '').indexOf((n + '')) > -1);
  return formattedArr && formattedArr.length > 0 ? formattedArr.sort().pop() : 'No results';
}

console.log(test(268, arr));
```

Comment: This isn't a solution to the OPs problem. Try it with `654` as input (and the corresponding values of course). The function should return `6554`, yours returns `6545`.